# In which table can I find payment amount information in wooCommerce database?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am actually integrating a woo-commerce website with an Accounting software Quickbooks where the integrated system(vb.net) will import all the paid and unpaid orders with corresponding paid amounts therefore need to know where certain information such a payment amount and method is saved

I searched in all the WooCommerce database tables looking for payment information such as (Payment amount, payment method) associated with the order but couldn't find
Even in the below table couldn't find anything related to payment

```
  Table: woocommerce_payment_tokens
  Table: woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description

Can someone please guide where is the payment amount and method saved. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce orders are a custom WordPress post type. All order information can be retrieved from the order object (Order post meta). WooCommerce provides getter functions to retrieve this data. For instance the order total and payment method:

```
$total = $order->get_total();
$payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
```

More information on the structure here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Order-and-Order-Line-Item-Data

If you are set on retrieving data from the database you can search the `wp_posts` table (since orders are a custom post type). You will have to search the `post_type` field for `shop_order`.

Then, you will have to search the `wp_postmeta` table for all the records with a `post_id` that matches the id of the order post.

Comment: The integrated system will be developed in vb.net. That's why I'm more concerned about knowing the table that stores the payment information rather the woo commerce objects functions @Terminator-Barbapapa

Comment: But the wp_postmeta has only four fields. I don't understand how can I extract order information such as payment amount and method from it. How can I make use of these fields to extract order information since those four fields are meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value

Comment: Correct. So in the `wp_post` table you can find all the orders, which are posts with a post type of `shop_order`. If you then take the id of an order post and search for all records in `wp_postmeta` where the `post_id` matches the id of the order post, you'll find all order meta (order total, payment method etc.).

Comment: but the wp_postmeta doesn't have any order payment information

Comment: Does your `wp_post` table have posts with `shop_order` as its type?

Comment: I just now understood... I was wrongly looking for the column name for payment_method etc There are no columns for that. Infact, the fields names and values are saved under meta_key and meta_value

Comment: But I noticed that when the order is placed with payment method COD or credit card, it doesn't show the payment_method information in the table unlike incase of bank account transfer. Do you have any idea why is that so?. How will we know using which method the paid orders were paid ?

Comment: That is strange. For COD for instance the meta value belonging to the `_payment_method` meta key should just be `cod`. Make sure the order you are checking does have a payment method set for it.

Comment: I just created a new order with COD. Checked in the db, the  _payment_method meta key already has cod. However the orders paid with Credit-card credimax doesn't have _payment_method meta key and its value. This payment gateway is a custom payment gateway which we developed and installed. Can it be because it is a custom PG?

Comment: That is very much possible. Although impossible to say for sure without seeing any code. You can easily check all order meta via de WooCommerce Store Toolkit plugin. This will print a complete list of the order meta on the order edit page. See if you can find the payment method there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will surely check that. Beside that, could you please suggest some good resources/documentation for learning wooCommerce functions and its codes so that I can have full control using the code

Comment: Where can i find the payment method fee and payout sum? I can parse it from the order page, but where is this info in the database?

Comment: Fees are stored in the `wp_woocommerce_order_items` table with an `order_item_type` of `fee`. I think your payout sum is generated by a third party plugin? If so, you should check within the code of that plugin how the payout sum is calculated and stored.